# Polynomials and functions

Tags: functions, polynomials, relations

if $y_1 = y_2$ 
then how we can prove that $x_1 = x_2$ in the following polynomial :
$${x_1}^3 + 2{x_1}^2 + 1 = {x_2}^3 +2{x_2}^2+1$$

(I want to see weather a relation is a function)

Answer (score 4):

I believe you want to show wheher a function is an injection.

$$f(x)=x^3+2x^2+1=x^2(x+2)+1$$

$$f(0)=1$$
$$f(-2)=1$$

Comment: Thank you. The question is if F(X) = {x^3}  then prove that:  f(b) -f(a)/b-a = b^2+ab+a^2 if I dont mistake

Comment: For that we just have to verify $(b-a)(b^2+ab+a^2)$ by expansion is indeed equal to $b^3-a^3$.